Meaning of “atom” and “molecule” in Dalton’s and Avogadro’s publications?
From the summaries here and here are the following correct?

Dalton (1805) used the words “atom” and “compound atom” in the same (or broadly similar) manner to current, simplistic understanding (i.e. with no explanation or understanding of sub-atomic structure)? That is, each element is composed of identical, indivisible atoms. Atoms combine in simple ratios to form “compound atoms” (molecules)?

Avogadro (1811) used the word “molecule” to mean the smallest (indivisible) item in a gas? So Avogadro’s use of the word “molecule” is this same as Dalton’s “compound atom”, or was there some difference in understanding of these words at time of publication?

I'm not clear if Avogadro distinguished between molecules and atoms.



"What is the question? – Mauricio". The sentences followed by questions marks. I think you have demonstrated you understand the concept.

The link provided to an earlier question and answer looks excellent, relevant and thorough. I will take time to study that and reply back if there is anything else I need clarification on. Thanks.

@Mauricio Your earlier answer is excellent and addresses my question. I will re-read your answer to grasp the detail and follow up the references.
